# applying CSS styles to floated DIVs

Tags: html, css

I want to apply dynamically additional CSS styles (to a set of floated div elements) which to move given div element to next line but the next div elements to be floated left. Using display block results in placing a given div on new line and the followed divs on the next line.

Example:

```
<fieldset>
  <div style="float:left;"></div><div style="float:left;"></div>
  <div style="display:block;"></div>
  <div style="float:left;"></div><div style="float:left;"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Wanted behavior:

```
<fieldset>
  <div style="float:left;"></div><div style="float:left;"></div>
  <div style="display:block;"></div><div style="float:left;"></div><div style="float:left;"></div>
</fieldset>
```

I have an HTML structure which I am not allowed to change (for instance separating some of the div elements in separate containers) and I want for these div elements inside the fieldset (let me say there are 6 div elements on the same level under fieldset) all to be floated (ordered) one after another but 4th div to be on a new line and the 5th to be after 4th on the same line. This is happening because some of the div elements might be not presented due to custom settings and this could lead to mismatch and confusion in the UI interface.

Comment: Did you try display: inline ?

Comment: why the `fieldset` ? and if you have the code of the wanted behavior so what is the issue then ? you have what you want

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What's added dynamically? Why aren't you using `inline-block` rather than floats, which are known to be troublesome?

Comment: Why are you using display Block?, rather you could've use inline-block to keep next div in same line

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But if you're targeting the floated divs, you can use this: `div[style*="float:left;"] { //your style }`

Comment: @user6016913: display:inline does not work for me because I want this 'inline' div to be on new line.

Comment: basically I have an HTML structure which I am not allowed to change (for instance separating some of the div elements in separate containers) and I want for these div elements inside the fieldset (let me say there are 6 div elements on the same level under filedset) all to be floated (ordered) one after another but 4th div to be on a new line and the 5th to be after 4th on the same line. This is happening because some of the div elements might be not presented due to custom settings and this could lead to mismatch and confusion in the UI interface.

Comment: @Temani Afif: if I have what I want I would not ask this question here. this is a case related to structural restrictions and I am trying by using javascript to go around and by applying extra additional CSS to achieve this behavior.

Comment: @nenito You should show your JS. Without it, we can only guess at what goes wrong. My guess is that you are replacing the element's style attribute, causing the current value to disappear. Also, all the info you are now giving in comments should be in the question.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I am using plain JS but I will provide more specific details tomorrow.